# Finding the longest path In an unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

i'm having a really tough time with this issue.

If I have a graphh, directed or undirected, unweighted and no cycles. How do I find the longest path?
Many algorithms I have seen rely on the graph being weighted, and reverse the weights and use bellman ford.
I ahve also seen dynamic programming solutions, but here people were simply looking for any path, I'm looking for one from s-t.

Ive been trying to break down the graph into subproblems, where I add one node a a time and give it a value of the parent that it is coming from plus one, but I just canoot get the logic right

can anyone provide an algorithm, exponential time would do, pseudopolynomial would be fantastic?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The weighted case is a pure generalization of the unweighted case: to reduce the unweighted case to the weighted case simply use a weighted graph with all weights equally weighted (for example weight of 1.)

Comment: In an undirected acyclic graph, the longest path from `s` to `t` is necessarily the **only** path from `s` to `t`. Otherwise, you can convert the unweighted graph to a weighted graph simply by setting all the weights to 1.

Comment: Also, what does it mean for a graph to be undirected and acyclic? As soon as a graph is undirected with one edge `(u,v)` it contains the trivial cycle `u->v->u`.

Comment: @ldog Just in case you're being serious, an undirected acyclic graph is *"an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by at most one path"* Quoted from wikipedia.

Comment: @user3386109: I was serious, as I've never dealt with them. It appears that the trivial cycle I describe is the only cycle allowed in an undirected acyclic graph (a misnomer in my opinion.) That was where my confusion resided.

Comment: @ldog Ah, I see. Yes, I suppose undirected acyclic graph *is* a misnomer. The formal name is a **tree** or a **forest**. The article I quoted is titled ["Tree (graph theory)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)).

Comment: I keep running into this claim that any agorithm which works for directed graphs, also works for undirected graphs, just by adding edges in both directions. But if we want to use dynamic programming, looking for optimal substructure, which we cannot find i undirected graphs. https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/11-Graph/Docs/longest-path-in-dag.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the graph can be directed **or** undirected lets reduce the problem only to directed graphs. If it's undirected then you should make edges from v -> w and from w -> v. You can use modified [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to measure the longest path starting from the node you pass to this function.
Then run this function to every node and get the maximum value.

Pseudocode for DFS:

```
DFS(Node v):
  if (v.visited?) return 0;
  v.visited = true;
  longestPath = 0;
  foreach(Node n : v.neighbours):
    longestPath = max(longestPath, DFS(n) + 1)
  return longestPath
```

Pseudocode for the problem:

```
longestPath(Node[] verticies):
  longestPath = 0
  foreach(Node v : vertices):
    foreach(Node w: vertices):
      w.visited = false;
    longestPath = max(longestPath, DFS(v))
  return longestPath;
```

It works in O(n^2) but I think this solution is straight forward.
Just to let you know, there is a solution which works O(n).

Comment: Thanks a lot! could you point me towards the O(n) solution?